# audio only plays on http not https

Tags: html, http, audio, https, stream

I have an audio live stream on via shoutcast server and it plays fine on http but doesn't play on https.

I currently have the stream address as http. I've tried switching the stream address to https in the audio tag but this had no effect.

Would it be possible to use 2 src attributes?
One http and one https and have it play whichever works?

I checked the site on whynopadlock and it gave me code to force https but as stated, the stream only plays on http. It says there are no mixed content errors.

None of my searches seem to turn up any answers

```
<audio controls="true" style="width: 234px; height: 30px">
    <source src="http://www.domain.tld:0000/;stream.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </source>[Stream Player]</audio>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The `<source>` element does not have a closing tag.

Comment: I fixed that but that  but that  had no effect on the player playing the stream on https. Still same result. The player shows up but is "greyed out".

Answer (score -1):

Google Chrome released an update which has stopped some SHOUTcast streams from working, this happens to Opera, IE, Edge, Safari and other Chromium-based browsers.

More specifically support for HTTP/0.9 over non-standard ports has been dropped. Since Shoutcast v1.x uses HTTP/0.9 and runs on a non-standard port (i.e. not 80 or 443) it gives the error "net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE" when you attempt to play a stream.

This will affect your player if your stream is running on a SHOUTcast v1 server and is on a port other than 80.

The issue relates to Chrome now blocking any non-HTTP traffic unless it's on port 80. SHOUTcast v1 uses the ICY protocol and so is blocked. Later versions of SHOUTcast Server, and other compatible server software, now use HTTP as the protocol to avoid this issue.

Upgrading to SHOUTcast v2 is recommended.

Cheers.